# Why is adding a subclass a of type in a collection is illegal?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, pecs

given this code snippet

```
    //Creates a list of List numbers
    List<List<Number>> num = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
    //Creates a list of List doubles
    List<List<Double>> doub = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
    //List of doubles
    List<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
    d.add(2.5);
    d.add(2.6);
    doub.add(d);

    num.add(d);//This code will not compile
```

Why is that num.add(doub) will not be allowed? isn't `List<List<Number>>` a super type of 
`List<List<Double>>` ?

Comment: Did you mean num.add(d) instead of num.add(doub)?

Comment: Generic types have to be exact unless you have allowed `? extends` sub types or `? super` super types.

Comment: I edited the code. He meant `num.add(d)`, otherwise the question is not interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Generics inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) is little different than our understanding of inheritance. If you would like to use subclass types you need to define bounds ([wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)) using either extends (or) super in generics.

[image]

Comment: can you provide me an example with regards to my example?

Comment: so will I do this? List<List< ? extends Number> ?

Comment: @KyelJmD: That should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a List of Lists to a List that takes a List. (not after edit I see)

Or maybe a bit less confusing:

```
Your num list can only add List<Number>, you are trying to add a List<List<Double>>.
```

Also, inheritance with generics doesn't work that way, even if you did add a List of doubles, it would not work.

If you define num like this:

```
    List<List<? extends Number>> num = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>();
```

Then you will be able to do this:

```
    num.add(d);
```

but not:

```
    num.add(doub);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<Double>` doesn't have anything to do with `List<Number>` as far as the compilre is concerned about the `List<>` part.

Therefore `List<List<Double>>` does not inherit from `List<List<Number>>` they are two completely different types by the Java Generics system. This is not an `extends` relationship as when building classes.

Answer (score 0):

Given the declared types, `doub.add(d)` and `num.add(doub)` imply inconsistent behavior of `add()`. If `doub.add(d)` works, I wouldn't expect `num.add(doub)` to as well.

Did you perhaps mean to test

```
num.add(d)
```

instead of

```
num.add(doub)
```

?